# Cassandra cluster error while running select query

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, datastax

I Create a cassandra cluster with 3 nodes and below are the configuration for cassandra.yaml file.

```
Node 1:
cluster_name: 'My Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
seed_provider:
- class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
    - seeds: 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2
listen_address: 10.0.0.1
native_transport_address: 10.0.0.1
native_transport_broadcast_address:1.2.3.4
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

Node 2:
cluster_name: 'My Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
seed_provider:
- class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
    - seeds: 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2
 listen_address: 10.0.0.2
 native_transport_address: 10.0.0.2
 native_transport_broadcast_address:1.2.3.4
 endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

Node 3:
cluster_name: 'My Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
seed_provider:
- class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
    - seeds: 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2
listen_address: 10.0.0.3
native_transport_address: 10.0.0.3
native_transport_broadcast_address:1.2.3.4
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

Also changed the  cassandra-rackdc.properties files for all the nodes as

```
Node1: 
dc=dc1
rack=rack1

Node2:
dc=dc1
rack=rack1

Node3:
dc=dc1
rack=rack2
```

I started dse service and my three nodes are up and status in showing as "UN" for all 3 nodes.

Now I am trying to create keyspace and tables. While creating keyspace I am using below command.

```
 CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS IntelliDish WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1': '1'} AND DURABLE_WRITES = false;
```

While doing this i got this warning:

```
Warning: schema version mismatch detected; check the schema versions of your nodes in system.local and system.peers.
```

And then I created tables and got the same warning. And when I am running select * from my_table then getting belwo error.

```
ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures (UNKNOWN_TABLE=[/10.0.0.3])" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'error_code_map': {'10.0.0.3': '0x0005'}, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}.
```

I thing I observed in error that its showing IP of my third node. I am not sure what is happening here.

Output of `nodetool describecluster`:

```
Cluster Information:    
    Name: Intellidish
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossipingPropertyFileSnitch 
    DynamicEndPointSnitch: enabled
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions: 407c57b2-94c9-33ed-80e2-b619ca5bfca1: [172.31.6.202, 172.31.7.89]
                     809561be-284f-3129-99ba-94fee6a364c6: [172.31.0.138]
```

Comment: Try changing rac2 to rac1 and use simple strategy for single dc.

Comment: Run a `nodetool describecluster`.  What does that tell you?

Comment: Also, your nodes can't all have the same `broadcast_address`.  That will create problems.

Comment: nodetool describecluster give below                                                          
                                                                                                                   
 Cluster Information:
 Name: Intellidish
 Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
 DynamicEndPointSnitch: enabled
 Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
 Schema versions:
  407c57b2-94c9-33ed-80e2-b619ca5bfca1: [172.31.6.202, 172.31.7.89]

  809561be-284f-3129-99ba-94fee6a364c6: [172.31.0.138]

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there is a schema disagreement.  This can happen when the network is or has been problematic.  The schema is stored just like data in any other table, except that it needs to be consistent across all nodes.  When a keyspace or table is added/edited, and one node cannot be reached, this is what happens.

The way around this, is to bounce Cassandra on the affected node.  If the schema versions still do not match, then try a rolling bounce of all nodes.  If that doesn't work, then decommission the bad node, wipe it, and re-add it to the cluster.